# How can I update CI Session from external native php code outside the application directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have buid a project in codeigniter and  I **set CI session** with key USER and value 'ABCD'.

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata('USER','ABCD');
```

And now I put some **native PHP code** outside the application directory and from there I have to **update the session** data having key USER to value 'XYZ' .

I can not change the session used in CI as it is being implemented in many pages. I can only change to native PHP code.

I also tried to use curl by making a function like this to update session through CI and make a function setcisession() in my controller

```
function setcises($key,$val)
{
    $cSession = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/controller/setcisession/$key/$val");
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    $result=curl_exec($cSession);
    curl_close($cSession);
}
```

My function in  Controller to set session

```
function setcisession($key,$value)
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->set_userdata($key,$value);  
}
```

but not luck I also tried

```
exec("wget --spider www.example.com/home/setcisession/$key/$val");
```

**Edited:** Actually, I create CI session when user login to web  with key- USER and and store the emailid which is used by the website many place.
And I had written social login code outside codeigniter application (in core php) directory and like to assign the email-id which returned from social login  to CI SESSION Key-'USER'
so that the website can identify the logedd in user

I know that I can do this by implementing social login code in CI

But **I Want to know how can we set CI session from core php code residing outside codeigniter application directory**

Comment: @RyanVincent I mean to modify  the current  session data set by inside application ,,, but modification should took place outside application using nativ (core) php code

Comment: @RyanVincent you right Actually, I create CI session on user when user login to web  with key- USER and and store the emailid which is used by the website many place
And I had written social login code outside codeigniter application (in core php) directory and like to assign the email-id which returned from social login  to CI SESSION Key-'USER'
so that the website can identify the logedd in user 

I know that I can do this by implementing social login code in CI 
But I Want to know how can we set CI session from core php code residing outside codeigniter application directory